# Resize Android screen resolution because of dead zone

Tags: android, screen-resolution, dpi, android-notification-bar

I need to resize my Android screen in order to be able to use the drop-down notification bar since the top and bottom parts of the screen are dead.

I was able to work with bottom buttons (back, home, recents) after using:

- wm overscan [reset|LEFT,TOP,RIGHT,BOTTOM]
- wm density [reset|DENSITY]

But this didn't work for the top part even though screen resolution and dpi were modified. I'm still not able to use the notification bar by swiping down from the top.
Is there any way to resize the area of effect of the notif. bar to achieve this or anything similar?

My screen resolution is 720x1280 - 320 dpi. It's a Sony Xperia Z3C.

Comment: You might have better luck on [android.SE]